# Get Windows 7's network status

Tags: c#, .net, networking, windows-7

In Windows 7 whenever the internet access gets lost, the network indicator turns yellow. I want to get this status in my software and set an alarm whenever the internet connection gets lost (an internet alarm). How can I get this status? All of the other libraries like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NetworkStatus.aspx), just show the status of disconnection (red) and otherwise say that the internet is available. I couldn't find any library that does this nor any API function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) there is a NetworkManager class that gets you both IsConnected and IsConnectedToInternet. Comes with some useful samples too. If you want to detect a change in status, do not poll - there are .NET events you can add handlers for just like adding a click handler.

Also see [Detect Internet V. local lan connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677702/detect-internet-v-local-lan-connection), [An elegant / simple way to check whether internet is available or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452361/an-elegant-simple-way-to-check-whether-internet-is-available-or-not), [I need a event to detect Internet connect/disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457773/i-need-a-event-to-detect-internet-connect-disconnect), etc.

Comment: Awesome answer. The one I was looking for is the Windows API Code Pack. It's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: The Windows API Code Pack mysteriously disappeared from Microsoft's site, hence the above link is dead; however the Internet never forgets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081665/windows-api-code-pack-where-is-it

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the network libary you found. Just look at the [Network Interface Class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NetworkStatus.aspx#NetworkInterface).
`OperationalStatus` can be more that up and down :)

Comment: nice answer, I was looking for this

Comment: Yes, it has more than Up and Down values but the problem is that when the internet is disconnected (the yellow icon) the `OperationalStatus` is still `Up` so it doesn't matter what other values it has.